# @angular/platform-webworker Vs @angular/platform-webworker-dynamic

Tags: angular

What is the difference between `@angular/platform-webworker` and `@angular/platform-webworker-dynamic`, what should I use if I have to run http promises in a web worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the difference is the same as with `platform-browser-dynamic` and `platform-browser`. `Platform-browser` is actually where the main functionality related to a browser platform like DOM renderers and browser adapters are placed. `Platform-browser-dynamic` is responsible for:

- Creating a JIT compiler`
- Compile AppModule and all its components - create factories
- Bootstrap AppModule factory

If you use AOT, you don't need `platform-browser-dynamic` at all:

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Now, the same applies to the `platform-webworker-dynamic`. It is [a very minimal package](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/6b79ab5abec8b5a4b43d563ce65f032990b3e3bc/packages/platform-webworker-dynamic/src) and contains [JIT compiler specific options](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6b79ab5abec8b5a4b43d563ce65f032990b3e3bc/packages/platform-webworker-dynamic/src/platform-webworker-dynamic.ts#L21).